# Coping folders from location listed in a text file to a new location

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.0

I have a text file "FromTo.txt" which contains folder paths, for e.g.

```
C:\Documents\Files\From\Folder1 
C:\Documents\Files\From\Folder2 
C:\Documents\Files\From\Folder3 
C:\Documents\Files\From\Folder4 
C:\Documents\Files\From\Folder5
```

I want to copy all folders from the path listed in "FromTo.txt" to a new folder. I am able to copy the files within a folder if I list the file names, but I am unable to copy the entire content of a folder listed in FromTo.txt to another folder.

Here is what i have so far...

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Documents\From\FromTo.txt | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Documents\To\"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, first you need to read the text file using `Get-Content`, then you may need to use the `-Recurse` parameter to do a recursive copy from source to destination :

```
Get-Content C:\Documents\From\FromTo.txt | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Documents\To" -Recurse }
```